# Interesting fragments of first-order logic induced by sorting?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, modal-logic

In first approximation, modal logic (I'm using the term loosely)
   can be understood as an interesting fragment of first-order logic
   (for simplicity I ignore e.g. how modal logic relates to
   second-order logics) with bounded/local quantifiers: modal
   operators can be thought of as abbreviations that encode
   quantification over relationally-accessible states in a convenient,
   variable-free notation. The [standard translation of modal logic into
   first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_translation) gives rise to interesting fragments like the
   finite variable fragments, the fragments closed under bisimulation,
   guarded fragments that have been investigated heavily, etc.
   The standard translation also allow us to push techniques, constructions and
   results between logics.

Modal logic is used because formulae and
   proofs in modal logic are more succinct, sometimes substantially
   so, than the corresponding first-order fragments.

In a similar sense, [many-sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic) first-order logic can be seen as a
   fragment of first-order logic by translating sorts
   into appropriate first-order predicates. Here I assume that we have more than one sort. Now my question: are there
   non-trivial results about fragments of first-order logic obtained by
   translating away sorts? I'm particularly interested in questions
   about the complexity of decision problems.

PS: I'm not sure if this question is suitable for mathoverflow. If not, please
feel free to close or move to a more appropriate venue.

Comment: I must be missing something. As a special case, if you translate away sorts from a many-sorted language with just one sort, you obtain the original formula. In other words, your fragment is trivially the full first-order logic.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It's probably me who's missing something. As far as I'm aware a formula like $\forall x.A$ where $x$ is of sort $S$, is translated into something like $\forall x.(P_S(x) \rightarrow A')$ where $A'$ is the corresponding translation of $A$ and $P_S$ is a predicate that formalises that something is in the sort $S$. I agree that in the special case of one sort that amounts to original FOL, but let's exclude that special case. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, if you do not require the translated sorts to exhaust the universe, you get the full first-order logic on a subset of the universe defined by a predicate. The principle is the same, this is still computationally as difficult as the first-order logic itself. In other words, since the translation needs to be faithful in the first place, you cannot get anything easier than (many-sorted) first-order logic.

Comment: You shouldn’t think of many-sorted logic as a *fragment* of one-sorted logic. It is actually an *extension* of one-sorted logic, and what the translation tells you is that this extension is inessential.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That's a good point. What I'm working with is (simpifying things a great deal) a many-sorted modal logic. I have empirical evidence that decision complexity is better than without sorting. I'm trying to organise my thoughts about this and am looking for related work.